# Using App Combat Theme and List View in Android

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app with tab views that needs the Android app combat theme. I want to implement a listview in this app. However, I need to extend the Main Activity Class with the AppCombat Activity Class and the List Activity Class, to get both working - which is not possible in one class, as far as I know. I´m a bit stuck here and any help would be appreciated.

`MainActivity.class`

```
package com.example.TodoList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.TodoList.db.TaskContract;
import com.example.TodoList.db.TaskDBHelper;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ListAdapter listAdapter;
    private TaskDBHelper helper;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private Button btnIconTextTabs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        updateUI();
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        btnIconTextTabs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIconTextTabs);
        btnIconTextTabs.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final EditText inputField = new EditText(this);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);


        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_task:
                builder.setTitle("Add an article to your shopping list");
                builder.setMessage("What would you like to add?");
                builder.setView(inputField);
                builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String task = inputField.getText().toString();

                        helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
                        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                        values.clear();
                        values.put(TaskContract.Columns.TASK, task);

                        db.insertWithOnConflict(TaskContract.TABLE, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
                        updateUI();

                    }
                });

                builder.create().show();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_remove_task:
                builder.setTitle("Remove an article from the shopping list");
                builder.setMessage("Did you found this article?");
                builder.setNegativeButton("Remove", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        String task = inputField.getText().toString();
                        helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
                        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.clear();
                        updateUI();
                    }
                });

            case R.id.action_show_mylocation:
                LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                Log.d("MyTagGoesHere", "This is my log message at the debug level here");
                //Intent intent=new Intent(this,LbsGeocodingActivity.class);
                //startActivity(intent);

                Intent GeoLocationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GeoActivity.class);
                //myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters

                MainActivity.this.startActivity(GeoLocationIntent);




        }

        builder.create().show();
        return true;

    }

    private void updateUI() {
        helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
                new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
                null, null, null, null, null);

        listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.task_view,
                cursor,
                new String[]{TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
                new int[]{R.id.taskTextView},
                0
        );

        this.setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    public void onDoneButtonClick(View view) {
        View v = (View) view.getParent();
        TextView taskTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.taskTextView);
        String task = taskTextView.getText().toString();

        String sql = String.format("DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s = '%s'",
                TaskContract.TABLE,
                TaskContract.Columns.TASK,
                task);


        helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        sqlDB.execSQL(sql);
        updateUI();
    }

    public void onSubmitPriceClick(View view) {
        Intent SubmitPriceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SubmitPriceActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(SubmitPriceIntent);
    }

    public void onScrollViewButtonClick(View view) {
        Intent SubmitPriceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, IconTextTabsActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(SubmitPriceIntent);
    }

    public void onWebViewButtonClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new
                Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://www.batprice.com:1337"));
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }


    public void onGeoLocationButtonClick(View view) {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Log.d("MyTagGoesHere", "This is my log message at the debug level here");
        Intent GeoLocationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GeoActivity.class);
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(GeoLocationIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnIconTextTabs:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, IconTextTabsActivity.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error "Cannot resolve method 'setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)'.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `App Combat` ... Ready to fight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are extending `AppCompatActivity` not [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html), `AppCompatActivity` does not inherently implement a `ListView`, so there is no `setListAdapter()` method. You need to either extend `ListActivity` (which does not extend `AppCompatActivity`, so this may not be preferable) or put a `ListView` in your layout and call `setAdapter()` on your `ListView`. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    ...
}
```

Or you can use an [`android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html), which is implemented in a similar manner to `ListActivity`.

Comment: Ok - so how would I do that in this Activity? When I import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment and extend the Main Activity with List Activity, I get errors.

Comment: @DWA2112 You would not extend `ListActivity` *and* import a `ListFragment`, it would be one or the other. I have a feeling you want to go with `ListFragment`, so change it back to `extends AppCompatActivity`. Then you need to create a separate class that `extends ListFragment`, and add that fragment into your `MainActivity`. Here is the documentation on adding fragments: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html